# python post request not generating response

Tags: python, forms, post, maps

I am trying to create a python script to calculate the distance between two cities using the latitude and longitude. Wherein I take the name of the cities from the user and find the coordinates using this [link](http://%3Chttps://gps-coordinates.org%3E).
However when posting the city name I am not able to generate a response( I get the whole html as a response)

```
import requests
city1=input("Enter the first city")
url="https://gps-coordinates.org/"
data={'address':city1}
r=requests.post(url,data=data)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: `requests` is used to get html responses, so i'm not sure what is wrong with you getting an `html` response. What did you expect? What's the expected output?

Comment: Obviously you have to parse the response for your required data. How ? that depends on the type of response data and format.

Comment: I parsed the response using beautiful soup. I get the whole html page as the response. Since I was expecting the output to be the latitude. I tried using soup.find(id="latitude") to get the coordinates but it prints nothing. I'm totally new to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page doesn't, as far as I can tell, offer an API. 
An API would make parsing the response easy. As they don't have an API you would have to parse the HTML and extract the relevant information. This could prove difficult as the page itself is only using Google Maps for finding the location.

Luckily Google offers an API for this task, the process of finding coordinates for a place given the name (this is often called geocoding). 
If you perform few requests you can use their API for free, under a certain limit you don't even need to set up an account with them.

The process is extensively described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

For your usecase you could easily adapt your script:

```
import requests

city1 = input("Enter the first city")
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json"
data = {"address": city1}
r = requests.post(url, params=data)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

Note that the parameters are supplied via the query string.

If you want to perform more than a few requests make sure to set up an account and send an API key with your requests, see the documentation for instructions on this.